# Theory behind Multivariate Imputation with Chained Equations

Tags: data-imputation, multiple-imputation, mice

Can anyone provide a reference to the theory that supports multivariate imputation with chained equations (MICE).  I know Rubin has provided this for MI but MICE is a Gibbs sampler (I have never seen this justified) and needs to have an epistemic basis, which I cannot find with any amount of searching.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Robert. Love the question... I have seen folks pose similar questions in the literature and in conferences.